# issues with regular expressions in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace a string with another

I have two strings I am looping over:

```
1: "I have a sentence with this_is_a_test in it." 
2: "I have another sentance with this_is_a_test_also in it".
```

I want to replace `this_is_a_test` in the first sentence with `hello` so it reads:

```
"I have a sentence with hello in it."
```

I do NOT want to touch the second sentence

Here is what I have:

```py
def exact_replace(string: str, old_word: str, new_word: str) -> str:
    """
    Finds an exact match of old_word in string and replaces it with new_word.
    :param string: original source string
    :param new_word: new string replacement
    :param old_word: string to search for in source
    :return:
    """
    pattern = re.compile(f"\\b{old_word}\\b")
    new_string = pattern.sub(new_word, string)
    return new_string
```

Unfortunately it matches in both strings

Comment: Your code should work, since `_` is a word char. `\b` detects word boundaries including positions with `_` next to them.

Comment: Don't forget to escape `old_word`: `pattern = re.compile(fr"\b{re.escape(old_word)}\b")`

Comment: from the docs `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)` so you can use count=1 to substitute only the first time